# Read TimeValue from pvts file with python

Tags: python, vtk

I have a pvts file that I'm trying to read with Python. Reading the point and cell data works fine, but I also want to extract the time value. For that, I have added

```xml
<FieldData>
<DataArray type="Float64" Name="TimeValue" NumberOfTuples="1">49.000000
</DataArray>
</FieldData>
```

To the end of the pvts file (before `<\PStructuredGrid>`)
This works fine for Paraview, but I'm unable to extract the value using the python [vtk](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/index.html) library. I think I should extract from the `vtkXMLPStructuredGridReader` object and not the `vtkStructuredGrid` based on what I have tried so far.

```py
reader = vtkXMLPStructuredGridReader()
reader.SetFileName(file)
reader.Update()
print(reader) # Has a line stating "ActiveTimeDataArrayName:TimeValue"
print(reader.GetTimeDataArray(0)) # Prints "TimeValue"
```

It shows me that it does see the "TimeValue" entry in my pvts.

```py
data = reader.GetOutput()
dim = data.GetDimensions()
print(data)
```

On the other hand, says that I have no FieldData. I think this is because I haven't added the TimeValue to the underlying vts files. Maybe I should, but paraview can use the one in the pvts, so I think it should also work via python. Just to be clear: I want to extract the `49.000000` from the file.

Rough structure pvts file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="PStructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian">
<PStructuredGrid WholeExtent=". . . . . ." GhostLevel=".">
<PPoints>
<PDataArray type="Float64" Name="coordinates" NumberOfComponents="3" format="appended" offset="0">
</PDataArray>
</PPoints>
<PPointData Scalars="scalars">
<PDataArray type="Float64" Name="." NumberOfComponents="1" format="appended" offset="0">
</PDataArray>
<PDataArray type="Float64" Name="." NumberOfComponents="1" format="appended" offset="0">
</PDataArray>
</PPointData>
<Piece Extent=". . . . . ." Source="<n>/field_<n>_0.vts"/>
<Piece Extent=". . . . . ." Source="<n>/field_<n>_1.vts"/>
<FieldData>
<DataArray type="Float64" Name="TimeValue" NumberOfTuples="1">49.000000
</DataArray>
</FieldData>
</PStructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

I'm also fine with a solution using an XML parser. I tried to look into that, but that also didn't look too easy at first glance.

Answer (score 1):

If you xml file is well-formatted you can search with iterparse():

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

for event, elem in ET.iterparse(file, events=('end',)):
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag =='DataArray':
        print(elem.text)
```